# Android - Want to transfer data from SQLITE db to Web Server

Tags: android

I have developed an offline data entry app in android where the user enters all the details which will be saved in sqlite db.

At the end of the day I want to transfer data from the sqlite db to a server which stores the data in PostgreSQL db. I didn't find any good answer as per my requirement.