# WCF Complex Web Service Access Android

Tags: android, wcf

I have problem accessing a complex WCF web service in Android. The details about my question are as follows:

A typical request to the WCF Web Service has the following XML:

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header><Action s:mustUnderstand="1"xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/manojService/MethodName</Action> 
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <MethodName xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <name>ABC</name>
      <Collection xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/YXZ.Model" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <d4p1:location>whatever</d4p1:location>
        <d4p1:OfficeLocation>
          <d4p1:Lattitude>28.5</d4p1:Lattitude>
          <d4p1:LocationID>0</d4p1:LocationID>
        </d4p1:OfficeLocation>
      </Collection>
      <Action>Add</Action>   
    </MethodName> 
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I am using simple SOAP concept for login using KSoap library as below:

```
try {   
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org/",
            "methodName");
    request.addProperty("name", "aaaa");

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE( "Service urls");
    androidHttpTransport.call("http://tempuri.org/manojService/MethodName", envelope);
    Object result = (Object) envelope.getResponse();
    String resultData = result.toString();
    System.out.println("result Data :-" + resultData);

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("error is occured :-" + e.getMessage());
}
```

If you have any solutions for sending the data of array type in soap then please let me know.

Comment: Your actual question probably lies in the final sentence, but it's not entirely clear what the actual problem is, how you tried to solve it, and where you got stuck?

Comment: Actually, want to access the WCF Web service according to my above xml request.

Comment: Recently I am getting this error:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You're better off *updating the question*, as opposed to commenting. If your edit is substantial this will bump your question, getting people's attention. Please make sure you're specific about your problem, and tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) to solve the problem.

Comment: Can you post on how your WCF service looks like? And what bindings were configured for it to help you out

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457758/android-want-to-transfer-data-from-sqlite-db-to-web-server/12457828#12457828