# Accessing RESTful WCF service from Android

Tags: android, wcf, rest

I have created one RESTful WCF service.  I have hosted this service in IIS on my laptop.  The service is accessible at below location.

```
http://pritam-pc:5050/Service1.svc/MyService/GooService/Customer/1
```

or

http:// 192.168.42.61:5050/Service1.svc/MyService/GooService/Customer/1  ( Using IP address )

I have turn on Wi-Fi on both my laptop and Android handset.

Now I want to access above url on my Android.

I have configured accesspoint on my Android

I have referred to below link for configuring the access point:

http://fszlin.dymetis.com/post/2010/05/10/Comsuming-WCF-Services-With-Android.aspx

But When I try to access WCF link from my android client it gives me error that 'The Web Page at http:// 192.168.42.61:5050/Service1.svc/MyService/GooService/Customer/1 might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to new web address.

Can someone guide me on how to access a RESTful WCF service which is hosted on a laptop and access it from Android phone.

Thanks,

Hemant

Comment: Is your laptop and mobile device on same wifi. If yes, try to access above url in web browser of your mobile. If your are not able to access the url, then your are facing connectivity issue.

Comment: look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457758/android-want-to-transfer-data-from-sqlite-db-to-web-server/12457828#12457828